# Create single table using php artisan migrate

Tags: laravel

I have executed this command to create a 'Users' table:

```
php artisan migrate
```

But after that I have created one new migration file using below command and want to create a 'Contact us' table

```
php artisan make:migration contactus
```

After both commands whenever I execute below command for generating the 'Contact us' table i get the following error: Table 'users' already exists

```
php artisan migrate
```

This is my code of migration file Contactus :

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('contactus',function(Blueprint $table){
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('email');
            $table->string('message');
            $table->timestamp('created_at')->nullable();
        });
    }
```

Is there any help i appreciated..

Comment: Just for extra info, can you also paste the migration you are trying to run?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like Users migration file has been edited and needs re migrating. Run: `php artisan migrate:refresh`

**Be warned** This will remove anything stored within the database so ensure you have a Seeder setup to place any relevant content back into the database.

In the event you get an `Laravel 5.4: Specified key was too long error` on the re migrate open AppServiceProvider and add:

`Schema::defaultStringLength(191);` into the `boot` function

Ensure you add `use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;` at the top of the AppServiceProvider file

Comment: i getting this one error while creating users table : SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1071 Specified key was too long; max key length is 767 bytes (SQL: alter table `users`   
  add unique `users_email_unique`(`email`))

Comment: Class 'App\Providers\Schema' not found  i getting this one error after adding this line

Comment: @camit1dk, add `use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;` at the top of the AppServiceProvider file

Comment: Working , i added this line at top 
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
Thank you

Comment: Perfect. Glad I could help.

Answer (score 1):

For this issue SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1071 Specified key was too long; max key length is 767 bytes (SQL: alter table users add unique users_email_unique(email))  open your AppServiceProvider under App/Providers folder and add the below code:

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
use Schema;
class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Bootstrap any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        Schema::defaultStringLength(191);
    }

    /**
     * Register any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        //
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try running below command to drop and migrate all the table again:

```
php artisan migrate:fresh
```

Note:
If your users table already migrated or exist and you wish to create a new table run below command :

```
php artisan make:migration contactus
```

then

```
php artisan migrate
```

Comment: i getting this error : Base table or view already exists: 1050 Table 'users' already exists  while execute at last "php artisan migrate"

Comment: just manually delete all the tables from your database and try running php artisan migrate command

Answer (score -1):

When using the CLI make sure not to blindly copy other migration files.

first run `php artisan make:migration create_contact_us_table`

Now open the migration file location at /database/migrations/create_contact_us_table.php

Edit your migration here, inside the UP function you should then have something like

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('contact_us', function(Blueprint $table){
        $table->increments('id');
        //Other table content
    });
}
```

After this you can run `php artisan migrate` again to run your migration.
If you keep getting this error, check your database and the migrations table.
It might not have saved that it already ran your previous migration. If this is the case remove all tables from the database and run `php artisan migrate` again. Should work then.

Comment: There are two table created 1. MIgration and 2. Users. But migration table is empty although created users table

Comment: Then there is your problem, just try removing all tables and re-run the migrate command.

Comment: same result. MIgration table has not any record. but i getting this error : SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1071 Specified key was too long; max key length is 767 bytes (SQL: alter table `users`   
  add unique `users_email_unique`(`email`))

May be migration is empty because of this error

Comment: add this to appserviceprovider.php public function boot()
    {
        Schema::defaultStringLength(191);
    }

Comment: Class 'App\Providers\Schema' not found getting this error after using this

Comment: Working , i added this line at top 
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
Thank you

Comment: This is because laravel has made some changes over the time, at @PrashantPrajapati said, open your app/Providers/appServiceProvider.php and add `Schema::defaultStringLength(191);` inside the boot function.

Comment: @Camit1dk make sure you flag the correct answer soo that others can reach to this issue directly